# Automate expired password change

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, passwords, oracle11g, stdin

In short, I want to automate a self-serve expired password change via a shell script without admin intervention.

Unfortunately, my approach fails and I'm uncertain why:

```
sqlplus -S /nolog << !
connect $userid/$password
xyzzy1                                            # my original uses $newpass
xyzzy1                                            # but results are the same
select distinct version from product_component_version;
exit;
!
```

produces

```
ERROR: ORA-28001: the password has expired        # connection succeeded
Changing password for USER
New password:                                     # carriage return succeeded?
Retype new password:                              # carriage return succeeded?
ERROR: ORA-00988: missing or invalid password(s)  # variables/STDIN may be NULL?
Password unchanged
SP2-0042: unknown command "xyzzy1" - rest of line ignored.
SP2-0042: unknown command "xyzzy1" - rest of line ignored.
SP2-0640: Not connected
```

It seems to ignore the passed responses to the request for a new password but at the same time, it doesn't hang.

Connecting manually and providing the same responses interactively *does* work.  I'm wondering why the password change process doesn't accept STDIN.

Any ideas?

Note: the year old question [Programmatically Change Expired Oracle DB Password?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5005999/programmatically-change-expired-oracle-db-password) was offered while writing this and, although it has exactly what I derived, it does not work for me.  I'm unsure of etiquette in this regard so apologies in advance for (re)posting.

My environment is Solaris and Oracle 10g/11g.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest connecting to the database as a privileged user and doing:

```
alter user user_name identified by new_password;
```

Comment: I appreciate and am aware of this approach but we need it to be done through the normal user without any privileged user intervention.

Answer (score 0):

### In C language

According to [OCI documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28395/oci08sca.htm#sthref1165) you can do it from the C API with the `OCIPasswordChange()` call:

> The `OCIPasswordChange()` call enables an application to modify a user's database password as necessary. This is particularly useful if a call to `OCISessionBegin()` returns an error message or warning indicating that a user's password has expired.

See also [API documentation for the `OCIPasswordChange()` function](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28395/oci17msc007.htm#i573853).

### In Python

OCI-based libraries for other languages may also expose this functionality. For example [Python's `cx_Oracle.connect()` function](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/module.html#cx_Oracle.connect) has a `newpassword` argument.